# Convert date and remove time from a string date php

Tags: php, datetime

I have this two DateTime values:`2018-08-19T16:00:00Z` and `1534694400`. For the first value i need to remove the `T16:00:00Z` from the date, for the second value, I need to convert it in a normal date. How I can do this using the `DateTime` class of php?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the first date:

```
$dt = new \DateTime('2018-08-19T16:00:00Z');
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d');
```

For timestamp:

```
$dt = new \DateTime();
$dt->setTimestamp(1534694400);
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was reading the `PHP` manual about this class but I was not sure on how to proceed. I've just one question about the values to convert, can I pass that values without problems if I extract them from an array?

Comment: @user9741470 Sure. If there're same values in array, you can pass them into DateTime's constructor without any worries. E.g. if `$array[0] = '2018-08-19T16:00:00Z'` then you can pass this value into constructor: `new \DateTime($array[0]);`

Comment: Ok, thank you for the help. I was testing the solution you've suggested and it works smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

  //1st
  $date=date_create("2018-08-19T16:00:00Z");
  echo date_format($date,"Y-m-d");

  //2nd
  $date=date_create();
  date_timestamp_set($date,1534694400);
  echo date_format($date,"Y-m-d");

?>
```